# Firebase Storage No Permission Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want anyone to be able to access the database and write to it.  I know that's not secure, but this is a pretty dummy site where I don't want people to have to create accounts.  There is no login.  Anytime I set my security for storage to public it lasts for a couple hours and then gets changed back right away.  Does firebase not allow this?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in that couple hours, did you do something like deploying using Firebase CLI?

Comment: I am deploying to hosting via cli- "firebase deploy".  I wouldn't think this would be changing the rules of storage?

Comment: I totally didn't think about rules being bundled in with hosting.  Make sense. This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem maybe is in rules defined in your project directory, it causes conflict with the rules in the Firebase console. Make sure that you also update the rules defined in your project directory.

More info: [Deployment Conflicts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment_conflicts)